# How to start creating a selection script , "inspect like what firebug do"?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does anyone know a DOM inspector javascript library or plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742210/does-anyone-know-a-dom-inspector-javascript-library-or-plugin)

I want to create a small tool on webproject which will let the user select tags on the page and i will save selections in an array for future use, so what i need is something near the functionality of firebug.
From where i can start? any good articles or tools can make things easier?

Comment: Do you mean selecting html tags? or tags like StackOverflow style tags?

Comment: Check this question:
[Does anyone know a dom inspector javascript library or plugin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/742210/does-anyone-know-a-dom-inspector-javascript-library-or-plugin)

Answer (score 2):

Could you do something like add a jquery function which does stuff on hovering and clicking on things you want to inspect?

e.g

```
$('div, p, img').hover(function(){
 // stuff to do on hover like highlight the object
    $(this).addClass('hover');
}, function(){
    $(this).removeClass('hover');
});

$('div, p, img').click(function(){  yourSpecialClickFunction();  });
```

Maybe you would have something somewhere which doesn't make the above do anything until an inspect button is clicked perhaps.