# Javascript: Let user select an HTML element like Firebug?

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, firebug

I want to write a browser (Chrome/FF) extension that needs to select an element on a web page.  I would like it to behave like Firebug's element inspector does.  You click the inspect arrow and you can then hover/highlight elements.  When you click on the element you want, the element is inspected.  I'm just interested in the code to allow a user to select an element - not in actually inspecting it or anything similar.

Because I'm writing an extension, it might be nice if you could provide non-jQuery/Prototype/etc.. code so I don't have to distribute that.

Comment: The easiest way is to check Firebug's code. If you've installed firebug, you can find the code inside the firefox profile folder. The default location in my linux machine  `~/.mozilla/firefox/random-chars.default/extensions/firebug@software.joehewitt.com/content/firebug` In Vista it is something like: `C:\Users\<user-name>\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\random-chars.default\extensions\firebug@software.joehewitt.com\content\firebug`

Comment: Well, it sounded like a great idea--at first.  Then I went and looked at the code and there's 50+ files all of reasonable size.  I don't even know where to begin and moreso, I don't know what to copy/paste/modify.

So, sadly this is definitely not the "easiest" thing.  I will probably home-brew something unless I find other solutions or others respond.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I wrote an implementation of this using jQuery as a component of another project. The source and documentation are available here: https://github.com/andrewchilds/jQuery.DomOutline

Answer (score 26):

I have recently required such a feature for a project I was working on, turned out that I had to use 4 sides to create a box because otherwise the `event.target` when you move the mouse would end up being the selector, and if I were to use `z-index: -1` it would be a bit *fishy* when you have a lot of elements that overlap...etc.

Here is a version that I have converted from my project for your benefit, it involves jQuery but it is extremely simple to convert to *vanilla* as only the `mousemove` & `css` methods from jQuery are used.

Step by step instructions.

First create the **5** HTMLElements that are required.

```
<div id="selector">
    <div id="selector-top"></div>
    <div id="selector-left"></div>
    <div id="selector-right"></div>
    <div id="selector-bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Secondly create a `mousemove` event on the `document` (or your container)

```
$(document).mousemove(function(event) { ... });
```

Then inside the `mousemove` we will do some basic checking to prevent selecting the `HTML, BODY, selector`

```
var id = event.target.id, tagName = event.target.tagName;

if(id.indexOf('selector') !== -1 || tagName === 'BODY' || tagName === 'HTML') {
   return;
}
```

Then we need to create a object to store our elements like so.

```
var elements = {
    top: $('#selector-top'),
    left: $('#selector-left'),
    right: $('#selector-right'),
    bottom: $('#selector-bottom')
};
```

After that we store some variables that hold some information about the target element like so.

```
var $target = event.target;
    targetOffset = $target.getBoundingClientRect(),
    targetHeight = targetOffset.height,
    targetWidth  = targetOffset.width;
```

Then all we do is calculate the **position** & **height** for all **4** sides of the selector like so.

```
elements.top.css({
    left:  (targetOffset.left - 4),
    top:   (targetOffset.top - 4),
    width: (targetWidth + 5)
});

elements.bottom.css({
    top:   (targetOffset.top + targetHeight + 1),
    left:  (targetOffset.left  - 3),
    width: (targetWidth + 4)
});

elements.left.css({
    left:   (targetOffset.left  - 5),
    top:    (targetOffset.top  - 4),
    height: (targetHeight + 8)
});

elements.right.css({
    left:   (targetOffset.left + targetWidth + 1),
    top:    (targetOffset.top  - 4),
    height: (targetHeight + 8)
});
```

All of the `+aFewPixels` is just a little optimization so that there is like `2px` gap in between the selector and the target.

For the `CSS` this is what I have come up with.

```
#selector-top, #selector-bottom {
    background: blue;
    height:3px;
    position: fixed;
    transition:all 300ms ease;
}

#selector-left, #selector-right {
    background: blue;
    width:3px;
    position: fixed;
    transition:all 300ms ease;
}
```

The `transition` gives the selector a very nice sliding effect.

## Try out a demo http://jsfiddle.net/rFc8E/9/

> Note: This also works for `transform: scale(2);` eg. when a element is scaled in size.

**Edit:** I've just updated this, I noticed that the `elements` object was **inside** the event handler, I've moved it outside in the demo, this is quite an important performance improvement because now, the `elements` object is only created **once** instead of **Hundreds of Thousands** if not **millions** of times inside the `mousemove` event.

Comment: Thanks! Great instructions and I like the slide effect in the demo!

Comment: Best solution! Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Brilliant explanation!

Answer (score 14):

One simple way to do it is to use an outline instead of a border:

```
.highlight { outline: 4px solid #07C; }
```

Just add and remove that class to any element you want to select/deselect (code below is not properly tested):

```
document.body.addEventListener("mouseover", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.target.addEventListener("mouseout", function (e) {
        e.target.className = e.target.className.replace(new RegExp(" highlight\\b", "g"), "");
    });
    e.target.className += " highlight";
});
```

Since you are using an outline, (which is supported by Chrome) instead of a border, elements will not jump around. I'm using something similar in my [EasyReader Extension](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/boamfheepdiallipiieadpmnklbhadhc).

Comment: this does not work when you want to highlight images `<img/>`

Answer (score 13):

### HTML Element Picker (Vanilla JS)

**Pick and highlight any HTML element on a page with only Vanilla JS! Tested in Chrome, FF, and Opera, doesn't work in IE.**

#### How it works:

What you need is actually very simple. You can just create an empty div box with a background in JS and move it around to highlight on top of hovered elements.
Here's the JS code:

```
const hoverBox = document.createElement("div");
console.log("hoverBox: ", hoverBox);
hoverBox.style.position = "absolute";
// change to whatever highlight color you want
hoverBox.style.background = "rgba(153, 235, 255, 0.5)";
// avoid blocking the hovered element and its surroundings
hoverBox.style.zIndex = "0";
document.body.appendChild(hoverBox);
let previousTarget;
document.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
    let target = e.target;
    if (target === hoverBox) {
        // the truely hovered element behind the added hover box
        const hoveredElement = document.elementsFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY)[1];
        if (previousTarget === hoveredElement){
            // avoid repeated calculation and rendering
            return;
        } else{
            target = hoveredElement;
        }
    } else{
        previousTarget = target;
    }
    const targetOffset = target.getBoundingClientRect();
    const targetHeight = targetOffset.height;
    const targetWidth = targetOffset.width;
    // add a border around hover box
    const boxBorder = 5;
    hoverBox.style.width = targetWidth + boxBorder * 2 + "px";
    hoverBox.style.height = targetHeight + boxBorder * 2 + "px";
    // need scrollX and scrollY to account for scrolling
    hoverBox.style.top = targetOffset.top + window.scrollY - boxBorder + "px";
    hoverBox.style.left = targetOffset.left + window.scrollX - boxBorder + "px";
});
```

[See Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Kevin_Li/p3nweobz/)
I also made an [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-element-picker) for the element picker with many more user configurations like background color, border width, transition, etc.
Here's the [GitHub page](https://github.com/AlienKevin/html-element-picker).

Comment: Looked at a bunch and this one is the simplest and cleanest

Comment: Adjustments to emulate Chrome inspector: hoverBox.style.zIndex = "9999";
hoverBox.style.opacity = .5;
hoverBox.style.pointerEvents = "none";

Answer (score 7):

I ended up asking in the Firebug group and got some great help:

http://groups.google.com/group/firebug/browse_thread/thread/7d4bd89537cd24e7/2c9483d699efe257?hl=en#2c9483d699efe257

Comment: Can you the code with us please? I want to do something similar

Comment: I'm doing a similar thing in one of my projects but I need to a little bit to this. After the element is selected, I want to get the Unique selector for that element. Any idea how to do that? Right now I'm hacking it...

If the selected element has ID attribute, we are good. Else I check for class and find the index of the selected element with similar class and if it doesn't then I take the Tag name repeat the same process.

But this method is totally not reliable. Is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a library that written in pure javascript as an alternative.

TheRoom JS: https://github.com/hsynlms/theroomjs

```
// theroom information template for target element
var template="";
template += "<div id=\"theroom-info\">";
template += "  <span id=\"theroom-tag\"><\/span>";
template += "  <span id=\"theroom-id\"><\/span>";
template += "  <span id=\"theroom-class\"><\/span>";
template += "<\/div>";
template += "";
template += "<style>";
template += "  #theroom-info {";
template += "    position: fixed;";
template += "    bottom: 0;";
template += "    width: 100%;";
template += "    left: 0;";
template += "    font-family: \"Courier\";";
template += "    background-color: #ffffff;";
template += "    padding: 10px;";
template += "    color: #333333;";
template += "    text-align: center;";
template += "    box-shadow: 0px 4px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);";
template += "  }";
template += "";
template += "  #theroom-tag {";
template += "    color: #C2185B;";
template += "  }";
template += "";
template += "  #theroom-id {";
template += "    color: #5D4037;";
template += "  }";
template += "";
template += "  #theroom-class {";
template += "    color: #607D8B;";
template += "  }";
template += "<\/style>";

var options = {
  template: template,
  showInfo: true
};

// initialize
theRoom.start(options);
```

[**codepen demo**](https://codepen.io/hsynlms/pen/jzjOyo)

Answer (score 2):

There was a similar question asked on Stackoverflow and it had lots of good answers:
[Does anyone know a DOM inspector javascript library or plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742210/does-anyone-know-a-dom-inspector-javascript-library-or-plugin)

For those who are looking for a quick and dirty solution:

http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/3006 is the easiest. Just put the code within `<script></script>` tags and you are good to go.

https://github.com/josscrowcroft/Simple-JavaScript-DOM-Inspector/blob/master/inspector.js is slightly better and still very easy to integrate in.

For a more sophisticated element inspector, you might want to check out the SelectorGadget as pointed by Udi. The inspector selection code is in http://www.selectorgadget.com/stable/lib/interface.js

Comment: The `Simple Javascript DOM inspector` looks very promising and a simple library.

Answer (score 2):

Also check this one out:

http://rockingcode.com/tutorial/element-dom-tree-jquery-plugin-firebug-like-functionality/

I found it pretty insightful.. and there's a demo here:

http://rockingcode.com/demos/elemtree/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

A very basic implementation can be done very easily without jQuery using `.onmouseover` and `e.target`:

```
var last,
    bgc;
document.onmouseover = function(e) {
    var elem = e.target;

    if (last != elem) {
        if (last != null) {
            last.classList.remove("hovered");
        }

        last = elem;
        elem.classList.add("hovered");
    }
}
```

With the CSS below if you want the children to change background as well:

```
.hovered,
.hovered * {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: black;
    background-color: red;
}
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/40mpte3n/8/)

---

If you want to select elements only near the edges (or select the parent near the edges and the element itself everywhere else) you could use `.getBoundingClientRect`.

```
var last;
window.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
  if(last) {
    last.style.background = ''; // empty is enough to restore previous value
  }
    var elem = e.target;

  if(elem === document.body || elem === document.documentElement) {
    return;
  }
  var bb = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
  var xr = e.pageX - bb.left; // x relative to elem
  var yr = e.pageY - bb.top; // y relative to elem
  var ew = 10; // edge width

  if(
       xr <= ew
    || xr >= bb.width - ew
    || yr <= ew
    || yr >= bb.height - ew
  ){
    elem.style.background = 'red';
    last = elem;
  }
});
```

Paired with some borders, this can be pretty usable for selection. [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/40mpte3n/6/)

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is to create 4 elements for the highlighting. They will form an **empty square**, and so your mouse events are free to fire. This is similar to this [overlay example](http://jsbin.com/xusira/1/) I've made.

The difference is that you only need the four elements (no resize markers), and that the size and position of the 4 boxes are a bit different (to mimick the red border). Then you can use `event.target` in your event handler, because it gets the real topmost element by default.

**Another approach** is to hide the exra element, get `elementFromPoint`, calculate then put it back.

They're faster than light, I can tell you. Even Einstein would agree :)

**1.) elementFromPoint overlay/borders - [[Demo1](http://jsbin.com/cotasi/2/)]** *FF needs v3.0+*

```
var box = $("<div class='outer' />").css({
  display: "none", position: "absolute", 
  zIndex: 65000, background:"rgba(255, 0, 0, .3)"
}).appendTo("body");

var mouseX, mouseY, target, lastTarget;

// in case you need to support older browsers use a requestAnimationFrame polyfill
// e.g: https://gist.github.com/paulirish/1579671
window.requestAnimationFrame(function frame() {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(frame);
    if (target && target.className === "outer") {
        box.hide();
        target = document.elementFromPoint(mouseX, mouseY);
    }
    box.show();   

    if (target === lastTarget) return;

    lastTarget = target;
    var $target = $(target);
    var offset = $target.offset();
    box.css({
        width:  $target.outerWidth()  - 1, 
        height: $target.outerHeight() - 1, 
        left:   offset.left, 
        top:    offset.top 
    });
});

$("body").mousemove(function (e) {
    mouseX = e.clientX;
    mouseY = e.clientY;
    target = e.target;
});
```

---

**2.) mouseover borders - [[Demo2](http://jsbin.com/yabidu/1/)]**

```
var box = new Overlay();

$("body").mouseover(function(e){
  var el = $(e.target);
  var offset = el.offset();
  box.render(el.outerWidth(), el.outerHeight(), offset.left, offset.top);
});​

/**
 * This object encapsulates the elements and actions of the overlay.
 */
function Overlay(width, height, left, top) {

    this.width = this.height = this.left = this.top = 0;

    // outer parent
    var outer = $("<div class='outer' />").appendTo("body");

    // red lines (boxes)
    var topbox    = $("<div />").css("height", 1).appendTo(outer);
    var bottombox = $("<div />").css("height", 1).appendTo(outer);  
    var leftbox   = $("<div />").css("width",  1).appendTo(outer);
    var rightbox  = $("<div />").css("width",  1).appendTo(outer);

    // don't count it as a real element
    outer.mouseover(function(){ 
        outer.hide(); 
    });    

    /**
     * Public interface
     */

    this.resize = function resize(width, height, left, top) {
      if (width != null)
        this.width = width;
      if (height != null)
        this.height = height;
      if (left != null)
        this.left = left;
      if (top != null)
        this.top = top;      
    };

    this.show = function show() {
       outer.show();
    };

    this.hide = function hide() {
       outer.hide();
    };     

    this.render = function render(width, height, left, top) {

        this.resize(width, height, left, top);

        topbox.css({
          top:   this.top,
          left:  this.left,
          width: this.width
        });
        bottombox.css({
          top:   this.top + this.height - 1,
          left:  this.left,
          width: this.width
        });
        leftbox.css({
          top:    this.top, 
          left:   this.left, 
          height: this.height
        });
        rightbox.css({
          top:    this.top, 
          left:   this.left + this.width - 1, 
          height: this.height  
        });

        this.show();
    };      

    // initial rendering [optional]
    // this.render(width, height, left, top);
}
```