# Is there an open source visual feedback library?

Tags: javascript, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript: Let user select an HTML element like Firebug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399797/javascript-let-user-select-an-html-element-like-firebug)

I want a simple way for people to spot errors on my webpage, mark the elements with the mouse and submit it via POST to another URL.

To see what I mean, click on "Help us to improve" in http://usabilla.com/

Comment: http://wpaoli.building58.com/2009/09/jquery-tab-slide-out-plugin/

Comment: That only does the slide out part. I'm interested in the DOM element selection via the mouse

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399797/javascript-let-user-select-an-html-element-like-firebug