# "Live" Vaadin application - how to update browser views

Tags: java, web-applications, vaadin, vaadin7

I have a Vaadin application, that I like to be "live", so that when different people have opened the application, they see changes made by another person directly, without refreshing their page.

How can I do this ?

The application consists currently of two panels, with components in them, which can be dragged and dropped.

Now I like to see a drag and drop in all open browser views, so that when person A has drag and dropped something, that this is automatically shown in the other views.

I currently can only make this, when the others are refreshing their view (I use Vaadin 7.6.6)

***UPDATE***

```
@Push
private static final class MyPanel extends Panel implements BroadcastListener {
    @Override
    public void attach() {
        Broadcaster.register(this);
        super.attach();
    }

    @Override
    public void detach() {
        Broadcaster.unregister(this);
        super.detach();
    }

    @Override
    public void receiveBroadcast(BroadcastMessage message) {
        System.out.println("BROADCOAST " + message);
    }
}

private Panel createTaskPanel(Status status) {
    Panel tasks = new MyPanel();
    tasks.setHeight("500px");

    VerticalLayout taskLayout = new VerticalLayout();
    taskLayout.setSpacing(true);
    taskLayout.setMargin(true);
    TaskContainer.get().getTasks().filter(task -> task.getStatus() == status).map(TaskComponent::new)
            .map(TaskComponent::getDragAndDrop).forEach(taskLayout::addComponent);

    DragAndDropWrapper wrapper = new DragAndDropWrapper(taskLayout);
    wrapper.setDropHandler(new DropHandlerImplementation(status, taskLayout));
    tasks.setContent(wrapper);
    return tasks;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need two things:

1. Enable server push,so that server changes are pushed to the clients
2. Some way to broadcast your changes to other UI instances.

Here a example of such a answer in more details

[Vaadin: get reference of UI to change data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39532142/vaadin-get-reference-of-ui-to-change-data/39537170#39537170)

Comment: thanks for the answer - I have to admit, I don't really know, how to apply this. I have edited my post and included my component for which I tried. The *enter* method or *initialize* method does not exists for a panel for me. So what to use there ? My DropHandler calls the Broadcaster.broadcast method in the drop method

Comment: The `attach()`/`detach()` methods should just be fine for this. Isn't it receiving broadcasts at the moment?

Comment: I receive the broadcasts, and if I add a new component in the `receiveBroadCast` method it works fine... but what must I do, to refresh the panels ? When a component has been drag and dropped, I remove the component from source panel and add it to the new panel. I tried this outside of the `receiveBroadCast` method and inside, but in neither cases the other view gets updated

Comment: it works partially. I have as caption of the panels the `componentCount` of the panel. This gets correctly updated, but I don't see the added/removed component in the panel. So something is happening...