# How to highlight an elements padding or margin like in web developer debug tools

Tags: html, css

In some of the web developer debug tools when you hover over an element the margin or padding is shown with a yellow color so you can see it easily.

[image]

How are they doing this? Is it possible to do the same thing with CSS?

**Update**:
It looks like they are adding layers over the top of the original element (see image - the A is not completely highlighted meaning it's not a background color).

Comment: No, this is not possible with CSS.

Comment: CSS can only select whole elements not parts, so no.

Comment: There's no magic property that will let those layers show up, but it surely can be done in some hacky way, the question is How and when you want this to happen ? and if you don't mind why ?

Comment: @ZohirSalak why does it have to be 'hacky'? Or you mean to do it with CSS? Gigawatts, every browser handles it differently, naturally. You can review how chromium handles it [here](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/tree/master/chrome/browser/devtools), they are just doing it at the application level. Can you do this with CSS, no. JavaScript, ofc. Lots of js repos on github and other answers on SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399797/javascript-let-user-select-an-html-element-like-firebug

Comment: @ZohirSalak It's so you can easily see the padding and margins if you wanted for learning and debugging reasons but for cases where you might not have a web developer tools installed.