# Javascript that mimics chrome DevTools -> Select an element in the page to inspect it

Tags: javascript, dom

i trying to find some javascript library that mimics and maybe extends the functionality of the chrome 
DevTools -> Select an element in the page to inspect it.
that will show me the HTML elements that the user mouse over it or select it.
i found this SOF thread which is outdated :

[Javascript: Let user select an HTML element like Firebug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399797/javascript-let-user-select-an-html-element-like-firebug)

Comment: I still see https://github.com/andrewchilds/jQuery.DomOutline

Comment: And it still works https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/a0vyz1ds/

Comment: looking for ready-made tested library if any exist  ...