# How to graphically select a element on a page outside the own website

Tags: web, web-crawler, csrf

So, I have a website where i need to insert a lot of products from our suppliers' website, and I would like to automate it.
I was reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399797/javascript-let-user-select-an-html-element-like-firebug), that would solve most of the `"front-end"` part, and on the backend than I only need to get the link of the page, and use a basic web crawler library to search on that page the given selector.

However I'm missing the part where I inject a possible `JS` library on the supplier website, in order to allow others to select the element with the mouse, and not to find it using something like the Chrome console.
I was thinking about fetching the source page on the server side, and that returning it, but all the resources like `CSS`, `JS`, images, will be blocked by `CSRF protection`, and so here's my question:

Are there ways to do this in any way?

Edit:
ok maybe it's not so clear what I want to achieve... here's how thing should go:
Someone decides to insert a new supplier, that he should set the CSS path for the product name, the CSS path for the product description etc etc (section where i appreciate suggestion), and then he only needs to insert the products links and the server will get the informations using the CSS path inserted before.

Comment: Have you considered using Selenium?

Comment: @Monofuse i should use Selenium for what?.. getting the CSS selector of the element?